# Retrieve date from subtracting variable number of days from date on calendar table

Tags: sql, db2

In our system we have a created  table that lists all the days that extends out to 20230 with a special field to specify a holiday/weekend.
SAMPLE BELOW:

```
DATE_FIELD   HOLIDAY_FIELD 
20200430         N
20200501         N  
20200502         Y
20200503         Y  
20200504         N
20200505         N
20200506         N
20200507         N
..............
```

My goal is to provide a date variable and subtract x number of days from the provided date.
The number of days is not a constant field, it can be different so FETCH and LIMIT wont work.

Ive already tried the code below and it works just as i want it if i always want to subtract 5 days from the given date:

```
 select date_field
    from table.calendar 
    where date_field <= '20200507' and holiday_field = 'N'
    order by date_field desc
    LIMIT 5,1
```

This will give me the result I want '20200430' because it skips the weekends.

However I want to be able to do something like below:

```
    select date_field
    from table.calendar 
    where date_field <= (variable date) and holiday_field = 'N'
    order by date_field desc
    LIMIT (variable n),1
```

But from what Ive read you cannot specify a variable for a fetch or limit.

Also to add this select statement will be used in a sub select.
So it most likely use as it is below:

```
    SELECT table1.*,
    (    select date_field
        from table.calendar 
        where date_field <= (table1.date) and holiday_field = 'N'
        order by date_field desc
        LIMIT (table1.days n),1 ) AS DATE

    from table1
    order by table1.date
```

Ive tried using row_number() but have no clue on how to pass the date and days variable.
This would start from the absolute top of the list and go down. I need it to start from a specific date.

```
with CALENDAR AS(                                    
SELECT x.*           FROM (                          
 select  date_field                             
 row_number() over() as rownum                       
 from table.calendar X 
 where holiday_field = 'N'         
 order by date_field                           
 ) AS t                                              
   )                                                 
 select table1.*, A.date_field 
from table1 
left join CALENDAR A on A.date_field <= table1.date  and A.rownum = 5
```

I also understand i could easily do this in a user created function but my ultimate goal is to produce a sql views to export to a 3rd party software. Their is severe performance slow down when using user functions in sql views.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you going to use variables in view without functions? The only way to to this is using global variables probably, but such variables must be set somehow in the session before running the statement using them. Is it ok for you the solution with 2 global variables and a view using them?

Comment: Hi mark thanks for the inquiry. Im ok with any solution as long as it does not require creating a function and can be used in a view. It doesn't even have to follow any of the methods i described above.  Im not sure how a global variable would work since you would need to know the value beforehand correct?

Answer (score 0):

The solution with global variables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE GV_DATE_FIELD VARCHAR(8) DEFAULT (TO_CHAR(CURRENT DATE, 'YYYYMMDD'));
CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE GV_DAYS INT DEFAULT 5;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CALENDAR_V AS
select date_field
from
(
select date_field, rownumber() over (order by date_field desc) rn
from calendar 
where date_field <= GV_DATE_FIELD and holiday_field = 'N'
)
where rn = GV_DAYS;

-- GV_DATE_FIELD == TO_CHAR(CURRENT DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')
-- GV_DAYS == 5
select * from CALENDAR_V;

SET GV_DAYS = 4;
-- GV_DATE_FIELD == TO_CHAR(CURRENT DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')
-- GV_DAYS == 4
select * from CALENDAR_V;
```

This couple of global variables are set for every session to their default values and work as parameters.
You may set their values explicitly (with the `SET` statement as described) before running the statement using them (the `CALENDAR_V` view in this case) to get the corresponding result.